# Find executable files, also those NOT marked executable

Tags: find, executable

How to Find binary files with or without executable permissions?  
I am working on a BASH script that would list in a path:  
* Shared Object files, 
* scripts, executable files, 
* static libraries  
  It should not display intermediate files like .o (object files).

Comment: You mean find all binary ELF files that don't have the execute bit?

Comment: Yes, nrathaus, I have files mixed up under number of directories (like in a tree), they do not have execute permissions: -rw-rw-r--, I know they contain executables, How to find / list executables?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  S.O. provides a mechanism whereby you can ask for help to fix errors in your code.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hi ghoti,
Thanks for the warm welcome.

I have a bash script, I am looking to display or list files in a directory hierarchy that are actually executable files and they are not marked executable, ya let the script list if they are marked executable as well :)

Comment: Hi gothi & nrathaus,

Is there any thing I could do to get +1?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me & thought of sharing...

```
find ./ -type f -name "*" -not -name "*.o" -exec sh -c '
    case "$(head -n 1 "$1")" in
      ?ELF*) exit 0;;
      MZ*) exit 0;;
      #!*/ocamlrun*)exit0;;
    esac
exit 1
' sh {} \; -print
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 file -i | grep "application/x-executable"
```

Comment: BTW: Its taken from here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40063/how-to-find-executable-filetypes

Comment: It displayed "some" executables, not all.

Comment: It runs relative to your path, go to "/" before running it

Comment: It also doesn't filter out those that are already marked as "executable"

Comment: Okay, I should list files those that are marked executable for example shared object files .so and others.

Answer (score 0):

The `file` program reports file type based on contents, so

```
file /bin/* | awk -F: '/executable/{print $1}'
```

reports potentially/actually executable files in /bin.

Comment: I wish to list all the files in hierarchy.
I tried: find ./ -name "*" | xargs file | awk -F: '/executable/{print $1}'
Not effective.

Comment: I tried the find | xargs | awk pipeline just now, and every file it reported is in some executable format.

Comment: And what does file report for these files? See if you can spot a pattern, and change the /foo/ argument to awk.

Comment: Hi arnt,

Is there any thing I could do to get +1? Thanks for your support.

Comment: find . -type f | xargs file | awk -F: '/script/{print $1} /ELF/{print $1}' perhaps?